# Items with both properties contained in a list

Tags: c#, performance, linq, intersect

I have a list of objects `X` (with the name `x`) with properties `a` and `b` of the same type `Location`. I also have a list of locations `y`. I need to find all objects in `x` for which `a` AND `b` are contained in the list `y`.

I can do it with loops and `Where`s but as both lists are huge, I need a really good performing solution. Is there any way to use `Intersect` in this case? Or something else?

**Here some pseudo code**

```
class X
{
    Location a;
    Location b;
}

GetMatches(List<X> x, List<Location> y) { ?? }
```

Comment: Can you use `HashSet` instead of `List` ? then the `Contains` method would run in `O(1)`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @mong-zhu, thank you, I will try it. It should be possible... I haven't thought about it.

Comment: @Fabjan, that would make the quite simple question pretty long and unreadable and cost me a plenty of time. As I don't need an answer with working code but ideas what to use, I prefer to have a short readable question and not additional overhead for both, me and the readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the y list to a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1).

```
var yHashSet = y.ToHashSet();
```

Then getting the matches is fast and easy:

```
private static List<X> GetMatches(List<X> x, HashSet<Location> y)
{
    return x
        .Where(item => y.Contains(item.a) && y.Contains(item.b))
        .ToList();
}
```

Make it parallel to become even faster:

```
private static List<X> GetMatchesParallel(List<X> x, HashSet<Location> y)
{
    return x
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .Where(item => y.Contains(item.a) && y.Contains(item.b))
        .ToList();
}
```